How to add trailing zeros to a time field that is less than 4 digits
I have a time field that is stored as a varchar and sometimes has less than 4 digits. The source that feeds the data use to have separate minute and hour fields and would just concat them together with a : in the middle. What would be the easiest way to address when the minute column is empty. Some examples:

Stored data: '10:' '20:5' '6:17' '9:5' '7:'
Desired format: '10:00', '20:05', '06:17', '09:05', '07:00'

There are other values similar like '9:'. Just looking for the simplest way to append zeros after the : if its blank.
The current way I got it display correctly is:
    IIF (  LEN( RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) ) >= 5  OR LEN( RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) ) =0 ,  RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME]))  ,
   IIF ( LEN (LEFT( RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) , CHARINDEX(':',  RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) )-1)) = 1 , '0' + LEFT( RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) , CHARINDEX(':',  RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) )-1), LEFT( RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) , CHARINDEX(':',  RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) )-1)) 
 + ':' +
  IIF ( LEN (RIGHT( RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) , CHARINDEX(':',  RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) )-1)) = 1 AND LEN( RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) ) < 4, '0' + RIGHT( RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) , CHARINDEX(':',  RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) )-1), RIGHT( RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) , CHARINDEX(':',  RTRIM( LTRIM([TIME])) )))
  ) AS  [TIME]

Thanks in advance!

Please show some sample input data and the expected result for that data. Your description sounds like you could do something like COALESCE(minute_column,'00'), but hard to tell without any details. Generally, you should use the correct datatype, this avoids such issues.

Use a proper time data type, never store date/time data in varchar columns.

What database engine?  What programming language are you using to execute the query?

@M.Rizzo The database engine used is T-SQL/SQL Server 2019. I am just running a query through a view to clean up some data. This data was inherited and cannot currently be changed.

@JonasMetzler some examples of values that need to be cleaned up are: '20:5' '6:17'  '9:5' '7:'

"I have a time field that is stored as a varchar"  Why???

@Eric, it was designed that way long before I got involved. This project use to gather the time from two separate text boxes and merge them together to get the time. It did not add leading zeros.

I don't have any of the columns names or the structure of the data, so this response is going to be very generic.  You could do a query like the following:
SELECT Column1, 
CASE WHEN LEN(RIGHT(Column1 , LEN(Column1) - CHARINDEX(':', column1))) = 
2 THEN Column1
WHEN LEN(RIGHT(Column1 , LEN(Column1) - CHARINDEX(':', column1))) = 1 THEN Column1 + '0'
ELSE Column1 + '00'
END AS FormattedColumn1
FROM table1;

This will handle formats like '10:00', '10:' , '9:0', '9:5'.  If there are other sceanrios you may need to add another case branch.
